# correct way of updating a QGraphicsView from QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have implemented a `QGraphicsScene` to contain instances of `QGraphicsItem` of a few different classes implemented by me. What I still don't understand is how the QGraphicsView associated with this scene is updated.

- When I call `addItem(QGraphicsItem)` the scene seems to redraw displaying the newly added items.
- When I change properties of my `QGraphicsItem` instances (e.g. calling `setVisible(bool)`) it seems that the view is not updated automatically.
- I currently call `QGraphicsScene::update()` without any arguments to draw the new state. this works in most cases, however in some of them it fails ( QGraphicsItem's `paint()` method is not called. I set a breakpoint there but whether it is reached or not depends on the zoom level in the QGraphicsView. I have to zoom out to a certain level for it to get called again).
- It doesn't work when I pass the bounding box of the changed item (scene coordinates) to  `QGraphicsScene::update(QRect)`. I can't see objects changing.

Can anybody give me a hint what is the correct way of implementing this? How do I notify the view correctly of changes in certain areas, what does the behaviour depend on. I think there's something wrong with my assumptions about coordinate systems. Thanks a lot for your explanations.

Comment: All points are equivalent since internally they call the update () method, it seems to me that the fourth point updates that QRectF but in coordinates of the scene and not of the view. In the third point, what "draw" method do you mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc I corrected my question, I'm speaking about the method to draw the QGraphicsItem which is actually called paint().

Comment: It would be great if you put the codes you used to affirm each point since as you point out you were based on experiments.

Comment: @eyllanesc the problem I have is that it is a lot of code.. I'll try to reduce it to show what I'm doing but that might take a little more time. It's several thousands of lines for the Scene, the GraphicsItems and the View

Comment: Your question is already 2 hours on the site and nobody complains that you delay in answering so take the necessary time (obviously do not abuse that since they could close your question). On the other hand if your code is gigantic then create new projects focused on the problematic functionality and verify that it continues to be problematic and then that will be the MRE, if it is not verified then your initial code (the giant project) has other errors.

Comment: my question is not "what is the problem in my code" but "how are updates triggered from QGraphicsScene" (in general). So if the answer is "should update automatically every time you change a QGraphicsItems" this answer is fine for me and I can check in my code why this does not happen

Comment: IMHO your code has problems getting false conclusions so your problem is *"what is the problem in my code"*